# How to display a camera frame in a Xamarin iOS ImageView, on iPad?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My app receives a stream of USB camera frames from a socket from another computer: a Windows 10 UWP app that reads frames from a USB camera, format ARGB32.

I want to show each frame on the iPad, to get a live view.

I assume the ImageView control is best.

The source of the frame is .NET UWP MediaFrameReader on Windows 10, from a Logitech HD1080p USB webcam.

More details on creation of the frame on Windows computer before it gets sent to iPad socket...

THIS CODE ON THE WINDOWS 10 RECEIVES FRAME FROM CAMERA...

```
        private void Reader_FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
    {

        // Update GUI frame count:
        SDKTemplate.Scenario1_DisplayDepthColorIR.present_frame_count++;

        // TryAcquireLatestFrame will return the latest frame that has not yet been acquired.
        // This can return null if there is no such frame, or if the reader is not in the
        // "Started" state. The latter can occur if a FrameArrived event was in flight
        // when the reader was stopped.
        //using (MediaFrameReference frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame())
        using (MediaFrameReference frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame())
        {
                // Display locally:
                _frameRenderer.ProcessFrame(frame);
        }
    }
```

THIS CODE PREPARES FRAME TO BE SENT FROM WINDOWS TO IPAD SOCKET...

```
        public void ProcessFrame( MediaFrameReference frame)
    {
        var softwareBitmap = FrameRenderer.ConvertToDisplayableImage(frame?.VideoMediaFrame);

        if (softwareBitmap != null)
        {
                ++arrived_frames;
            uint frame_size_bytes = frame.Buffer​Media​Frame.Buffer.Length;
            // Swap the processed frame to _backBuffer and trigger UI thread to render it
            softwareBitmap = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _backBuffer, softwareBitmap);

            // UI thread always reset _backBuffer before using it.  Unused bitmap should be disposed.
            softwareBitmap?.Dispose();

            ////////////////////////   DISPLAY FRAME LOCALLY   /////////////////////////

            // Changes to xaml ImageElement must happen in UI thread through Dispatcher
            var task = _imageElement.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                async () =>
                {
                    // Don't let two copies of this task run at the same time.
                    if (_taskRunning)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    _taskRunning = true;

                    // Keep draining frames from the backbuffer until the backbuffer is empty.
                    SoftwareBitmap latestBitmap;
                    while ((latestBitmap = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _backBuffer, null)) != null)
                    {
                        var imageSource = (SoftwareBitmapSource)_imageElement.Source;
                        await imageSource.SetBitmapAsync(latestBitmap);

                        SDKTemplate.SOURCE.Frames_To_iPad.send_frame_packet( latestBitmap, frame_size_bytes );

                        latestBitmap.Dispose();
                    }

                    _taskRunning = false;
                });

            ////////////////////////////  SEND TO IPAD   //////////////////////////////





        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `Image` property of the [`UIImageView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIImageView/) each time a new frame is received, but I have doubts whether this can happen quickly enough to display a video smoothly as you will need to convert each frame to a `UIImage` before you can assign it to the `Image` property.

I just did a quick test using local HD sized images, and it did seem to track fairly smoothly. The images were PNG images stored in the app bundle, I am not sure what format your images will be in when you receive them from the socket.

Comment: I just added the code that takes the frame from the camera and sends it to the iPad socket, for display on iPad. I examined with debugger and format is ARGB32 and about 1.2MBytes.